# jQuery is not working after partial postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, partial-postback

I have this jquery functions below in external file. So after partial postback jquery is not working. I need to load jquery from server side on partial postback.

can someone show me what I need to call in this code and how to load jquery

```
jQuery(function ($) { var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); var browserVersion = (userAgent.match(/.+(?:rv|webkit|khtml|opera|msie)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/) || [0, '0'])[1]; var isIE6 = (/msie/.test(userAgent) && !/opera/.test(userAgent) && parseInt(browserVersion) < 7 && (!window.XMLHttpRequest || typeof (XMLHttpRequest) === 'function')); var body = $('body'); var currentSettings; var callingSettings; var shouldResize = false; var gallery = {}; var fixFF = false; var contentElt; var contentEltLast; var modal = { started: false, ready: false, dataReady: false, anim: false, animContent: false, loadingShown: false, transition: false, resizing: false, closing: false, error: false, blocker: null, blockerVars: null, full: null, bg: null, loading: null, tmp: null, content: null, wrapper: null, contentWrapper: null, scripts: new Array(), scriptsShown: new Array() }; var resized = { width: false, height: false, windowResizing: false }; var initSettingsSize = { width: null, height: null, windowResizing: true }; var windowResizeTimeout; $.fn.nyroModal = function (settings) { if (!this) return false; return this.each(function () { var me = $(this); if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'form') { me.unbind('submit.nyroModal').bind('submit.nyroModal', function (e) { if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return false; if (me.data('nyroModalprocessing')) return true; if (this.enctype == 'multipart/form-data') { processModal($.extend(settings, { from: this })); return true } e.preventDefault(); processModal($.extend(settings, { from: this })); return false }) } else { me.unbind('click.nyroModal').bind('click.nyroModal', function (e) { if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return false; e.preventDefault(); processModal($.extend(settings, { from: this })); return false }) } }) }; $.fn.nyroModalManual = function (settings) { if (!this.length) processModal(settings); return this.each(function () { processModal($.extend(settings, { from: this })) }) }; $.nyroModalManual = function (settings) { processModal(settings) }; $.nyroModalSettings = function (settings, deep1, deep2) { setCurrentSettings(settings, deep1, deep2); if (!deep1 && modal.started) { if (modal.bg && settings.bgColor) currentSettings.updateBgColor(modal, currentSettings, function () { }); if (modal.contentWrapper && settings.title) setTitle(); if (!modal.error && (settings.windowResizing || (!modal.resizing && (('width' in settings && settings.width == currentSettings.width) || ('height' in settings && settings.height == currentSettings.height))))) { modal.resizing = true; if (modal.contentWrapper) calculateSize(true); if (modal.contentWrapper && modal.contentWrapper.is(':visible') && !modal.animContent) { if (fixFF) modal.content.css({ position: '' }); currentSettings.resize(modal, currentSettings, function () { currentSettings.windowResizing = false; modal.resizing = false; if (fixFF) modal.content.css({ position: 'fixed' }); if ($.isFunction(currentSettings.endResize)) currentSettings.endResize(modal, currentSettings) }) } } } }; $.nyroModalRemove = function () { removeModal() }; $.nyroModalNext = function () { var link = getGalleryLink(1); if (link) return link.nyroModalManual(getCurrentSettingsNew()); return false }; $.nyroModalPrev = function () { var link = getGalleryLink(-1); if (link) return link.nyroModalManual(getCurrentSettingsNew()); return false }; $.fn.nyroModal.settings = { debug: false, blocker: false, windowResize: true, modal: false, type: '', forceType: null, from: '', hash: '', processHandler: null, selIndicator: 'nyroModalSel', formIndicator: 'nyroModal', content: null, bgColor: '#000000', ajax: {}, swf: { wmode: 'transparent' }, width: null, height: null, minWidth: 400, minHeight: 300, resizable: true, autoSizable: true, padding: 25, regexImg: '[^\.]\.(jpg|jpeg|png|tiff|gif|bmp)\s*$', addImageDivTitle: false, defaultImgAlt: 'Image', setWidthImgTitle: true, ltr: true, gallery: null, galleryLinks: '<a href="#" class="nyroModalPrev">Prev</a><a href="#"  class="nyroModalNext">Next</a>', galleryCounts: galleryCounts, galleryLoop: false, zIndexStart: 100, cssOpt: { bg: { position: 'absolute', overflow: 'hidden', top: 0, left: 0, height: '100%', width: '100%' }, wrapper: { position: 'absolute', top: '50%', left: '50%' }, wrapper2: {}, content: {}, loading: { position: 'absolute', top: '50%', left: '50%', marginTop: '-50px', marginLeft: '-50px'} }, wrap: { div: '<div class="wrapper"></div>', ajax: '<div class="wrapper"></div>', form: '<div class="wrapper"></div>', formData: '<div class="wrapper"></div>', image: '<div class="wrapperImg"></div>', swf: '<div class="wrapperSwf"></div>', iframe: '<div class="wrapperIframe"></div>', iframeForm: '<div class="wrapperIframe"></div>', manual: '<div class="wrapper"></div>' }, closeButton: '<a href="#" class="nyroModalClose" id="closeBut" title="close">Close</a>', title: null, titleFromIframe: true, openSelector: '.nyroModal', closeSelector: '.nyroModalClose', contentLoading: '<a href="#" class="nyroModalClose">Cancel</a>', errorClass: 'error', contentError: 'The requested content cannot be loaded.<br />Please try again later.<br /><a href="#" class="nyroModalClose">Close</a>', handleError: null, showBackground: showBackground, hideBackground: hideBackground, endFillContent: null, showContent: showContent, endShowContent: null, beforeHideContent: null, hideContent: hideContent, showTransition: showTransition, hideTransition: hideTransition, showLoading: showLoading, hideLoading: hideLoading, resize: resize, endResize: null, updateBgColor: updateBgColor, endRemove: null }; function processModal(settings) { if (modal.loadingShown || modal.transition || modal.anim) return; debug('processModal'); modal.started = true; callingSettings = $.extend(true, settings); setDefaultCurrentSettings(settings); if (!modal.full) modal.blockerVars = modal.blocker = null; modal.error = false; modal.closing = false; modal.dataReady = false; modal.scripts = new Array(); modal.scriptsShown = new Array(); currentSettings.type = fileType(); if (currentSettings.forceType) { if (!currentSettings.content) currentSettings.from = true; currentSettings.type = currentSettings.forceType; currentSettings.forceType = null } if ($.isFunction(currentSettings.processHandler)) currentSettings.processHandler(currentSettings); var from = currentSettings.from; var url = currentSettings.url; initSettingsSize.width = currentSettings.width; initSettingsSize.height = currentSettings.height; if (currentSettings.type == 'swf') { setCurrentSettings({ overflow: 'visible' }, 'cssOpt', 'content'); currentSettings.content = '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="' + currentSettings.width + '" height="' + currentSettings.height + '"><param name="movie" value="' + url + '"></param>'; var tmp = ''; $.each(currentSettings.swf, function (name, val) { currentSettings.content += '<param name="' + name + '" value="' + val + '"></param>'; tmp += ' ' + name + '="' + val + '"' }); currentSettings.content += '<embed src="' + url + '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="' + currentSettings.width + '" height="' + currentSettings.height + '"' + tmp + '></embed></object>' } if (from) { var jFrom = $(from).blur(); if (currentSettings.type == 'form') { var data = $(from).serializeArray(); data.push({ name: currentSettings.formIndicator, value: 1 }); if (currentSettings.selector) data.push({ name: currentSettings.selIndicator, value: currentSettings.selector.substring(1) }); showModal(); $.ajax($.extend({}, currentSettings.ajax, { url: url, data: data, type: jFrom.attr('method') ? jFrom.attr('method') : 'get', success: ajaxLoaded, error: loadingError })); debug('Form Ajax Load: ' + jFrom.attr('action')) } else if (currentSettings.type == 'formData') { initModal(); jFrom.attr('target', 'nyroModalIframe'); jFrom.attr('action', url); jFrom.prepend('<input type="hidden" name="' + currentSettings.formIndicator + '" value="1" />'); if (currentSettings.selector) jFrom.prepend('<input type="hidden" name="' + currentSettings.selIndicator + '" value="' + currentSettings.selector.substring(1) + '" />'); modal.tmp.html('<iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" name="nyroModalIframe" src="javascript:\'\';"></iframe>'); $('iframe', modal.tmp).css({ width: currentSettings.width, height: currentSettings.height }).error(loadingError).load(formDataLoaded); debug('Form Data Load: ' + jFrom.attr('action')); showModal(); showContentOrLoading() } else if (currentSettings.type == 'image') { debug('Image Load: ' + url); var title = jFrom.attr('title') || currentSettings.defaultImgAlt; initModal(); modal.tmp.html('<img id="nyroModalImg" />').find('img').attr('alt', title); modal.tmp.css({ lineHeight: 0 }); $('img', modal.tmp).error(loadingError).load(function () { debug('Image Loaded: ' + this.src); $(this).unbind('load'); var w = modal.tmp.width(); var h = modal.tmp.height(); modal.tmp.css({ lineHeight: '' }); resized.width = w; resized.height = h; setCurrentSettings({ width: w, height: h, imgWidth: w, imgHeight: h }); initSettingsSize.width = w; initSettingsSize.height = h; setCurrentSettings({ overflow: 'visible' }, 'cssOpt', 'content'); modal.dataReady = true; if (modal.loadingShown || modal.transition) showContentOrLoading() }).attr('src', url); showModal() } else if (currentSettings.type == 'iframeForm') { initModal(); modal.tmp.html('<iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" src="javascript:\'\';" name="nyroModalIframe" id="nyroModalIframe"></iframe>'); debug('Iframe Form Load: ' + url); $('iframe', modal.tmp).eq(0).css({ width: '100%', height: $.support.boxModel ? '99%' : '100%' }).load(iframeLoaded); modal.dataReady = true; showModal() } else if (currentSettings.type == 'iframe') { initModal(); modal.tmp.html('<iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" src="javascript:\'\';" name="nyroModalIframe" id="nyroModalIframe"></iframe>'); debug('Iframe Load: ' + url); $('iframe', modal.tmp).eq(0).css({ width: '100%', height: $.support.boxModel ? '99%' : '100%' }).load(iframeLoaded); modal.dataReady = true; showModal() } else if (currentSettings.type) { debug('Content: ' + currentSettings.type); initModal(); modal.tmp.html(currentSettings.content); var w = modal.tmp.width(); var h = modal.tmp.height(); var div = $(currentSettings.type); if (div.length) { setCurrentSettings({ type: 'div' }); w = div.width(); h = div.height(); if (contentElt) contentEltLast = contentElt; contentElt = div; modal.tmp.append(div.contents()) } initSettingsSize.width = w; initSettingsSize.height = h; setCurrentSettings({ width: w, height: h }); if (modal.tmp.html()) modal.dataReady = true; else loadingError(); if (!modal.ready) showModal(); else endHideContent() } else { debug('Ajax Load: ' + url); setCurrentSettings({ type: 'ajax' }); var data = currentSettings.ajax.data || {}; if (currentSettings.selector) { if (typeof data == "string") { data += '&' + currentSettings.selIndicator + '=' + currentSettings.selector.substring(1) } else { data[currentSettings.selIndicator] = currentSettings.selector.substring(1) } } showModal(); $.ajax($.extend(true, currentSettings.ajax, { url: url, success: ajaxLoaded, error: loadingError, data: data })) } } else if (currentSettings.content) { debug('Content: ' + currentSettings.type); setCurrentSettings({ type: 'manual' }); initModal(); modal.tmp.html($('<div/>').html(currentSettings.content).contents()); if (modal.tmp.html()) modal.dataReady = true; else loadingError(); showModal() } else { } } function setDefaultCurrentSettings(settings) { debug('setDefaultCurrentSettings'); currentSettings = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.nyroModal.settings, settings); setMargin() } function setCurrentSettings(settings, deep1, deep2) { if (modal.started) { if (deep1 && deep2) { $.extend(true, currentSettings[deep1][deep2], settings) } else if (deep1) { $.extend(true, currentSettings[deep1], settings) } else { if (modal.animContent) { if ('width' in settings) { if (!modal.resizing) { settings.setWidth = settings.width; shouldResize = true } delete settings['width'] } if ('height' in settings) { if (!modal.resizing) { settings.setHeight = settings.height; shouldResize = true } delete settings['height'] } } $.extend(true, currentSettings, settings) } } else { if (deep1 && deep2) { $.extend(true, $.fn.nyroModal.settings[deep1][deep2], settings) } else if (deep1) { $.extend(true, $.fn.nyroModal.settings[deep1], settings) } else { $.extend(true, $.fn.nyroModal.settings, settings) } } } function setMarginScroll() { if (isIE6 && !modal.blocker) { if (document.documentElement) { currentSettings.marginScrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft; currentSettings.marginScrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop } else { currentSettings.marginScrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft; currentSettings.marginScrollTop = document.body.scrollTop } } else { currentSettings.marginScrollLeft = 0; currentSettings.marginScrollTop = 0 } } function setMargin() { setMarginScroll(); currentSettings.marginLeft = -(currentSettings.width + currentSettings.borderW) / 2; currentSettings.marginTop = -(currentSettings.height + currentSettings.borderH) / 2; if (!modal.blocker) { currentSettings.marginLeft += currentSettings.marginScrollLeft; currentSettings.marginTop += currentSettings.marginScrollTop } } function setMarginLoading() { setMarginScroll(); var outer = getOuter(modal.loading); currentSettings.marginTopLoading = -(modal.loading.height() + outer.h.border + outer.h.padding) / 2; currentSettings.marginLeftLoading = -(modal.loading.width() + outer.w.border + outer.w.padding) / 2; if (!modal.blocker) { currentSettings.marginLeftLoading += currentSettings.marginScrollLeft; currentSettings.marginTopLoading += currentSettings.marginScrollTop } } function setTitle() { var title = $('h1#nyroModalTitle', modal.contentWrapper); if (title.length) title.text(currentSettings.title); else modal.contentWrapper.prepend('<h1 id="nyroModalTitle">' + currentSettings.title + '</h1>') } function initModal() { debug('initModal'); if (!modal.full) { if (currentSettings.debug) setCurrentSettings({ color: 'white' }, 'cssOpt', 'bg'); var full = { zIndex: currentSettings.zIndexStart, position: 'fixed', top: 0, left: 0, width: '100%', height: '100%' }; var contain = body; var iframeHideIE = ''; if (currentSettings.blocker) { modal.blocker = contain = $(currentSettings.blocker); var pos = modal.blocker.offset(); var w = modal.blocker.outerWidth(); var h = modal.blocker.outerHeight(); if (isIE6) { setCurrentSettings({ height: '100%', width: '100%', top: 0, left: 0 }, 'cssOpt', 'bg') } modal.blockerVars = { top: pos.top, left: pos.left, width: w, height: h }; var plusTop = (/msie/.test(userAgent) ? 0 : getCurCSS(body.get(0), 'borderTopWidth')); var plusLeft = (/msie/.test(userAgent) ? 0 : getCurCSS(body.get(0), 'borderLeftWidth')); full = { position: 'absolute', top: pos.top + plusTop, left: pos.left + plusLeft, width: w, height: h} } else if (isIE6) { body.css({ marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0 }); var w = body.width(); var h = $(window).height() + 'px'; if ($(window).height() >= body.outerHeight()) { h = body.outerHeight() + 'px' } else w += 20; w += 'px'; body.css({ width: w, height: h, position: 'static', overflow: 'hidden' }); $('html').css({ overflow: 'hidden' }); setCurrentSettings({ cssOpt: { bg: { position: 'absolute', zIndex: currentSettings.zIndexStart + 1, height: '110%', width: '110%', top: currentSettings.marginScrollTop + 'px', left: currentSettings.marginScrollLeft + 'px' }, wrapper: { zIndex: currentSettings.zIndexStart + 2 }, loading: { zIndex: currentSettings.zIndexStart + 3}} }); iframeHideIE = $('<iframe id="nyroModalIframeHideIe" src="javascript:\'\';"></iframe>').css($.extend({}, currentSettings.cssOpt.bg, { opacity: 0, zIndex: 50, border: 'none' })) } contain.append($('<div id="nyroModalFull"><div id="nyroModalBg"></div><div id="nyroModalWrapper"><div id="nyroModalContent"></div></div><div id="nyrModalTmp"></div><div id="nyroModalLoading"></div></div>').hide()); modal.full = $('#nyroModalFull').css(full).show(); modal.bg = $('#nyroModalBg').css($.extend({ backgroundColor: currentSettings.bgColor }, currentSettings.cssOpt.bg)).before(iframeHideIE); modal.bg.bind('click.nyroModal', clickBg); modal.loading = $('#nyroModalLoading').css(currentSettings.cssOpt.loading).hide(); modal.contentWrapper = $('#nyroModalWrapper').css(currentSettings.cssOpt.wrapper).hide(); modal.content = $('#nyroModalContent'); modal.tmp = $('#nyrModalTmp').hide(); if ($.isFunction($.fn.mousewheel)) { modal.content.mousewheel(function (e, d) { var elt = modal.content.get(0); if ((d > 0 && elt.scrollTop == 0) || (d < 0 && elt.scrollHeight - elt.scrollTop == elt.clientHeight)) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation() } }) } $(document).bind('keydown.nyroModal', keyHandler); modal.content.css({ width: 'auto', height: 'auto' }); modal.contentWrapper.css({ width: 'auto', height: 'auto' }); if (!currentSettings.blocker && currentSettings.windowResize) { $(window).bind('resize.nyroModal', function () { window.clearTimeout(windowResizeTimeout); windowResizeTimeout = window.setTimeout(windowResizeHandler, 200) }) } } } function windowResizeHandler() { $.nyroModalSettings(initSettingsSize) } function showModal() { debug('showModal'); if (!modal.ready) { initModal(); modal.anim = true; currentSettings.showBackground(modal, currentSettings, endBackground) } else { modal.anim = true; modal.transition = true; currentSettings.showTransition(modal, currentSettings, function () { endHideContent(); modal.anim = false; showContentOrLoading() }) } } function clickBg(e) { if (!currentSettings.modal) removeModal() } function keyHandler(e) { if (e.keyCode == 27) { if (!currentSettings.modal) removeModal() } else if (currentSettings.gallery && modal.ready && modal.dataReady && !modal.anim && !modal.transition) { if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 40) { e.preventDefault(); $.nyroModalNext(); return false } else if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 38) {   }
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to execute some javascript after partial postback, you can follow either of these methods:

- Assuming you have a `<asp:ScriptManager />` in your page you can include a function called `pageLoad()`

  ```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     function pageLoad()
     {
      // JS to execute during full and partial postbacks
     }
    </script>
  ```
- Or check out this link that explains about executing javascript during partial postbacks

http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2009/06/inject-dynamic-javascript-into-aspnet.html

- Another way is to use the Sys.Application.add_init handler as given below:

  Sys.Application.add_init(appl_init);

  ```
  function appl_init() {
      var pgRegMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
       pgRegMgr.add_beginRequest(StartHandler);
       pgRegMgr.add_endRequest(EndHandler);
  }
  function StartHandler() {
      // your js
  }
  function EndHandler() {
      // your js
  }
  ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks K25 for this answer. I used the pageLoad function in REgisterstartup and it saved me from a major headache.

Answer (score -1):

To call this function after partial postback, what u need to do is re-register external js file. The following code does this.

```
private void RegisterClientStartupScript()
{
    string path = Page.ResolveUrl("~/Script/slider.js");
    ScriptManager sManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
    if (sManager != null && sManager.IsInAsyncPostBack)
    {            
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
           this.updSpeech, typeof(string),"include-js",
           path); 
         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.updSpeech, this.updSpeech.GetType(), "SliderScript",
            "FunctionName();", true); 

    }
    else
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("SliderScript", path);
    }
}
```

Call this function on every page load i.e outside (!isPostback). This code gets reference to external js file and in case it is a partial postback,it registers it with the scriptmanager. In case it is a normal postback it registers it with clientScript.

**EDIT**

Try giving the jquery function a name and then call ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript().see the above code and replace FunctionName() with the name of ur jquery function. In the above code this.updSpeech is the updatepanel.

Comment: On page load this code works, after partial postback stop working